# MVC Upload Imagem e enviar a base de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Boa Noite estou a fazer uma loja online para uma disciplina e gostaria de saber se alguem me poderia ajudar a criar o upload de imagem para a Base de Dados.

O intuito é adicionar na pagina de admin e aparecer no index.

Página onde se cria o produto:

```
    @model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar Novo Filme";
}

<h2>Adicionar Novo Filme</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Filme</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Titulo">Titulo</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ReleaseDate">Data de Lançamento</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Genero">Género</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Preco">Preço</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Img">Imagem</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Img, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Img, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

O Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


        public ActionResult Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
        {
            var GenreLst = new List<string>();

            var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
                           orderby d.Genre
                           select d.Genre;

            GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLst);

            var movies = from m in db.Movies
                         select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
            }


            return View(movies);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price,Img")] Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Movies.Add(movie);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(movie);
        }


        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price,Img")] Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(movie);
        }


        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
            db.Movies.Remove(movie);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


    }
}
```

A Base de dados é:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movies] (
    [ID]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ReleaseDate] DATE           NOT NULL,
    [Genre]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Price]       MONEY          NULL,
    [Img] IMAGE NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Movies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Leadnnd, chegou a olhar essa pergunta?https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14285/upload-de-imagens

Comment: @LeadnndPereira A única diferença é que nesse caso, o upload não é salvo no banco e sim em um diretório (o que é o mais indicado). A menos que seja um requisito salvar o conteúdo do arquivo no banco de dados, recomendaria você seguir as instruções do Ricardo Pontual

Comment: Seria mesmo preciso o armazenamento na base de dados para aparecer na pagina principal mais facilmente pois não daria pela pasta.